# how to redirect stdout and stderr to a file while showing stderr to screen?

Tags: bash, shell

The script should redirect all the output (stdout and stderr) to a log file, and only display stderr to the screen (notifying user if an error happens). The command `tee` may help but don't know how to write it.

Thanks.

P.S., thanks lihao and konsolebox for the answer, but is there a way to keep the output in order. For example:

```
$ cat test.sh
echo "to stdout..1"
echo "to stderr..1" >&2
echo "to stdout..2"
echo "to stderr..2" >&2

$ sh test.sh 2>&1 >test.log | tee -a test.log
to stderr..1
to stderr..2

$ cat test.log
to stdout..1
to stdout..2
to stderr..1
to stderr..2
```

Command: `{ sh test.sh 2> >(tee /dev/fd/4); } 4>&1 >test.log` has the same output.

Answer (score 1):

how about the following:

```
cmd args 2>&1 >logfile | tee -a logfile
```

Comment: That could also be usable but it would create two handles for the file.

Comment: if you're going to use this you might want to append to instead of overwrite `logfile` in the first command (the one before the pipe)...

Answer (score 0):

You should map normal stdout to another file descriptor (`4`), make the file the default output, then use tee to redirect output to the new file descriptor through `/dev/fd`. Of course you'd need process substitution to pass stderr output to `tee`:

```
{ cmd args 2> >(exec tee /dev/fd/4); } 4>&1 >file
```

If you want to make a general redirection for the script, place this at the beginning of it:

```
exec 4>&1 >file 2> >(exec tee /dev/fd/4)
```

You can restore normal output with:

```
exec >&4 4>&-
```